# Control never appears after ScaleTransform Animation

Tags: wpf, animation

I am attempting to animate a ScaleTransform from 0 to 1 in order to reveal a control.

The following code seems PERFECT to me. i have copied the approaches from other questions here on StackOverflow. Yes, the animation runs (at least Completed is raised) however, the visual never occurs. Since this is going from 0 to 1, the control never appears. I have tried to manually set it to 1 (without animation) and there is no problem there, works.

Please assume begin == 0 && duration == 3000 && from == 0 && to == 1:

```
// setup
var _Storyboard = new Storyboard
{
    BeginTime = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(begin),
    Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(duration)),
};
_Storyboard.Completed += (s, e) => { if (callback != null) callback.Invoke(); };

// force Scale Transform
var _ScaleTransform = new ScaleTransform() { ScaleX = from, ScaleY = from };
food.RenderTransform = _ScaleTransform;

// animate X
var _AnimateX = new DoubleAnimation { From = from, To = to };
_Storyboard.Children.Add(_AnimateX);
Storyboard.SetTarget(_AnimateX, _ScaleTransform);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(_AnimateX, new PropertyPath(ScaleTransform.ScaleXProperty));

// animate Y
var _AnimateY = new DoubleAnimation { From = from, To = to };
_Storyboard.Children.Add(_AnimateY);
Storyboard.SetTarget(_AnimateY, _ScaleTransform);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(_AnimateY, new PropertyPath(ScaleTransform.ScaleYProperty));

// start
_Storyboard.Begin();
```

Is there something obvious?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initial value of the Transform must be set before animation